# ecs-cli doesn't work with MFA - AssumeRoleTokenProviderNotSetError

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, aws-cli, amazon-ecs, aws-config

I got this error  :

```
Error executing 'up': AssumeRoleTokenProviderNotSetError: assume role with MFA enabled, but AssumeRoleTokenProvider session option not set.
```

when trying to execute this command :

```
ecs-cli up --force --capability-iam --size 2 --instance-type t2.medium --cluster-config [my-config] --aws-profile [my-profile] --port [xxxx] [xx]
```

With this configuration :

- `.aws/config`

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1

[profile my-profile]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/xxxxxx
region = eu-west-1
source_profile = default
mfa_serial=arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:mfa/xxxxxxxxxxx
```

- `.aws/credential` 
  **: they are generated with get-session-token**

```
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
aws_session_token = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

- `.ecs/config`

```
version: v1
default: default
clusters:
  my-config:
    cluster: cluster_name
    region: eu-west-1
    default_launch_type: EC2
  default:
    cluster: default
    region: eu-west-1
    default_launch_type: EC2
```

- `.ecs/credential`

```
version: v1
default: my-profile
ecs_profiles:
  my-profile:
    aws_access_key_id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    aws_secret_access_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Also tried to use temporary session, but I got the same error. Thanks for help !

Comment: Somewhere you have to call [get-session-token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html) where you can specify the MFA token from your device. I'm sure that `ecs-cli` supports that?

Comment: Sorry @Marcin my *.aws/credential* file  is not complete.I forgot to write "aws_session_token = XXXXXXXX". I called get-session-token with a MFA token from my device, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: get-session-token should give you new access key id, secret key id and token. Did you use them?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, I use them. Sorry if my description is not crystal clear

Comment: No problem. I just speculate now, but if you manually run `get-session token`, place credentials generated in .aws (or .ecs?) config files, then you don't need `[profile my-profile]`. I think that because you use this profile for ecs-cli, aws requires from you new mfa credentials.

Comment: I tried this way but I still got this error @Marcin